# Get boundaries from segmented image

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, scikit-image

I'm trying here to get the boundaries of a segmented image using find_boundaries function in skimage. but when applying the following code all i got is matrix of false or zeros.
Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import io
from skimage.morphology import watershed
from skimage.segmentation import mark_boundaries, find_boundaries
from skimage.filters import sobel

myimage = io.imread('15746.png')
plt.imshow(myimage, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
plt.show()

hist = np.histogram(myimage, bins= np.arange(0,256))
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(8,3))
ax1.imshow(myimage, cmap=plt.cm.gray, interpolation='nearest')
ax1.axis('off')
ax2.plot(hist[1][:-1], hist[0], lw=2)
ax2.set_title('histogram of grey values')
plt.show()

selected_pixles = []
for i in hist[1][:-1]:
    if hist[0][i] >= 700:
        selected_pixles.append(i)

image = sobel(myimage)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 3))
ax.imshow(image, cmap=plt.cm.gray, interpolation='nearest')
ax.axis('off')
ax.set_title('elevation_map')

markers = np.zeros_like(myimage)
markers[myimage < min(selected_pixles)] = 1
markers[myimage > max(selected_pixles)] = 2
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 3))
ax.imshow(markers, cmap=plt.cm.gray, interpolation='nearest')
ax.axis('off')
ax.set_title('markers')

seg = watershed(image, markers=markers)
#print(np.shape(seg[1]))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 3))
ax.imshow(seg, cmap=plt.cm.gray, interpolation='nearest')
ax.axis('off')
ax.set_title('segmentation')
#plt.show()



'''bound = mark_boundaries(seg,seg, mode='thick')
#print(np.shape(bound[0]))
plt.imshow(bound, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
plt.show()'''

bounder = find_boundaries(seg, mode='thick').astype(np.uint8)
print(bounder)
```

and here's the result:

```
[[0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 ..., 
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]]
```

Here's the image:
[image]

So what am i missing here ?

Comment: Please post the relevant image.

Comment: i edited my post and added the image

Answer (score 1):

Your script is working fine and the output does not consist only of zeros.  When I plot it, I see:

[image: boundary plot]

When you print the array, numpy summarizes the output; and since the outer values are all 0, that's what you see.

Comment: can i use the output array to be a descriptor ?... and if i want to make a shape descriptor for such image, what do you think the best way for it ?

Comment: To make a descriptor, skeletonize the boundary, extract its coordinates, and then use one of the standard mechanisms, such as Fourier coefficients (http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e161/lectures/fd/node1.html).